# Referential integrity across multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, constraints

What would be the easiest way to ensure any data entering a table matches data from a corresponding relation? In my example, I've got a a sports club. Players can play sports without a team. I want to enforce that the player plays the sport BEFORE joining a team.

Here are my tables:

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS sports (
    sport_id SERIAL,
    sport_name VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(sport_id)
    );

create table IF NOT EXISTS players (
    player_id SERIAL,
    player_name VARCHAR(50),
    player_phone VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(player_id)
    );

create table IF NOT EXISTS players_sports (
    player_id INT REFERENCES players(player_id),
    sport_id int REFERENCES sports(sport_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (player_id, sport_id)
    );

create table IF NOT EXISTS teams (
    team_name VARCHAR(50),
    sport_id INT,
    captain_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (sport_id, captain_id) 
        REFERENCES players_sports(sport_id, player_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (team_name, sport_id)
    );

create table IF NOT EXISTS has_players (
    team_name VARCHAR(50),
    sport_id int,
    player_id INT REFERENCES players(player_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (team_name, sport_id) 
        REFERENCES teams(team_name, sport_id),
    PRIMARY KEY(team_name, sport_id, player_id)
    );

CREATE TYPE DAY AS ENUM (
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thursday',
  'Friday',
  'Saturday',
  'Sunday'
);

create table IF NOT EXISTS time_slot (
    training_id SERIAL,
    training_day DAY,
    training_time TIME,
    team_name VARCHAR(50),
    sport_id int,
    FOREIGN KEY (team_name, sport_id) 
        REFERENCES teams (team_name, sport_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (training_id)
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to enforce that the player plays the sport BEFORE joining a team.

Add another [FK constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS has_players (
  team_name varchar(50)
, sport_id  int
, player_id int
, PRIMARY KEY(team_name, sport_id, player_id)
, FOREIGN KEY (team_name, sport_id)
    REFERENCES teams(team_name, sport_id)
, FOREIGN KEY (player_id, sport_id)
    REFERENCES players_sports(player_id, sport_id)
);
```

You can include the same column in multiple FK constraints (if that's what kept you from doing it).

Comment: @MaxAtkins: The simplicity is the beauty of it. :)